# Render All Frontend in one Scene

Tags: react-native

Hello Guys is this a good stuff in React native Environment I create all Scenes as Components and being rendering it without using react navigator or something like that ?

Comment: Please kindly include your source code to better explain your issue/question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of app. If it's a very simple ui and functionality then it's ok but not good. Bu if it has so much screens and have complex functionalities, then break it down to different screens and use navigation. In fact it would be a good practice to use different screens and navigation. It also is good practice for memory management.